# On es file explorer, how can you move files into /mnt/sdcard_ext

Tags: hp-pro-slate-12

When I try to move the file it says it only works in internal storage how can I move the file to external storage?

Answer (score 0):

To do that you must have root and root explorer enabled. Just launch es file explorer. Swipe left to right or go to the menu section and just belie enable root explorer. If you don't find it tap on tools. Next just above tap local. Then device. You can then locate the mnt/sdcard path. You can paste whatever you want there and do a reboot